# Injecting a Angular service into controller results in $injector:unpr error (using AngularBooter)

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-service, angularjs-controller

I am using the [AngularBooter](https://github.com/brandonkboswell/AngularBooter) for Angular in my app.

Here is my code:

```
emp.boot();

emp.services.SocialService = ['$http', '$q', function ($http, $q) {

    var deferred = $q.defer();

    $http.get('/api/feed').then(function (data) {
        deferred.resolve(data);
    });

    this.getStatuses = function ()
    {
        return deferred.promise;
    }

}];

emp.controllers.StatusesController = ['$scope','SocialService', '$interval',  function($scope, SocialService, $interval) {

    var statuses = SocialService.getStatuses();

    statuses.then(function(data) {
        $scope.statuses = data;
        console.log($scope.statuses);
    });
}];
```

From what I understand the error: `Error: [$injector:unpr]` is a sign that the service isn't being registered or implemented correctly, I have tried a few things but keep running into the same problem. Any ideas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two problems:

1) You are booting before you register your stuff (at least in the code you provided). Do `emp.boot()` right at the bottom after everything has been defined.

2) Your service is not returning anything. For instance, if you add `return {};` at the very bottom of your service function, it should magically not throw the error anymore, but you probably want to return something more interesting than that.

You can see this in action by uncommenting the line that returns the object and see Angular start working again.
http://codepen.io/alex-wilmer/pen/QbwNGz?editors=101

I imagine you probably want something like this:

```
emp.services.SocialService = ['$http', '$q', function ($http, $q) {
  var deferred = $q.defer();

  $http.get('/api/feed').then(function (data) {
    deferred.resolve(data);
  });

  return {
    getStatuses = function () { // don't mix brace placement!
      return deferred.promise;
    }
  };
}];
```

Comment: Perfect! I did actually manage to figure this out myself but your answer was spot on, I moved the boot below everything and obviously I needed to actually return something! (Im pretty new to these frontend frameworks). Cheers for the assistance :)